# Scala: Как правильно передать функцию как аргумент другой функции?

Tags: функции, scala

Есть функция:

```
sigma(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int, a: Int)(f: (Int, Int, Int, Int) => Double): Double
```

Мне нужно ее передать в другую функцию:

```
bigPi(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int, a: Int)('Тут должна быть sigma'):Double
```

Как правильно определить тип функции sigma и передать ее как аргумент bigPi? Заранее спасибо за уделенное время.

Answer (score 1):

По сути второй лист параметров - это вторая функция возвращаемая первой. Держи:

```
def sigma(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int, a: Int)(f: (Int, Int, Int, Int) => Double): Double = 1.0

def bigPi(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int, a: Int)(foo: (Int, Int, Int, Int) => ((Int, Int, Int, Int) => Double) => Double):Double = 3

bigPi(1, 2, 3, 4)(sigma)
```

На самом деле вопрос интересный, компилятор не со всеми случаями справляется видимо из-за того что функции высшего порядка в скале представлены через `FunctionN`(`Function1`, `Function2`...)